# Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration create archive with duplicate and nested modules

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, dsc

When I'm using Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration to create archives for azurerm-template dsc-extensions, it has started to create archives with duplicate modules.

Running Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration on a configuration with these imports:

[image: All dsc-resource imports]

Creates this archive:

[image: Duplicate names]

With duplicate names, and inside each module theres is several modules of the same type and version nested:

[image]

Anyone has an explanation for this or have experienced the same behaviour?

Im using the latest azureRM modules (1.2.0) on windows 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

See if there are duplicate paths in `$env:PSModulePath` for "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules". If are duplicates, update the environment variable using this command:

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath.Replace("C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;","")
```